# how to use colon separated values in oracle sql where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Table

```
ColA    ColB
1       Testa:testb:Testc:testd
```

How can I find matching rows based on a single value found within the colon-delimited values? I've tried this but it doesn't match rows where ColB has more than one embedded value:

```
Select * from Table
      Where ColB = 'testc' and ColA =1
```

Comment: And your question is?
Maybe try to refactor this table structure (?) to be more clear

Comment: This question does not make any sense. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW you can also use INSTR:

```
Select *
from Table
Where INSTR(':' || ColB  || ':', ':testc:') > 0 and ColA = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `like`:

```
Select *
from Table
Where (':' || ColB  || ':' like '%:testc:%') and ColA = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Gordon's really good answer, according to your example, case sensitivity might be an issue here.

If your data only contain plain letters with no diacritical marks and or accents, probably using `UPPER` would be sufficient:

```
Select *
from Table
Where (':' || UPPER(ColB)  || ':' like UPPER('%:testc:%')) and ColA = 1;
```

For more advanced usage, and for a recent enough version of Oracle (10g release 2 or above), you can [set `NLS_COMP` to `LINGUISTIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams120.htm#REFRN10117) and [change the `NLS_SORT` settings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG271) for the current session to use *case insensitive* sort of your choice. As an example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=FRENCH_CI;

Select *
from Table
Where (':' || ColB  || ':' like '%:testc:%') and ColA = 1;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38999 or an example illustrating my point.